# Webpack - exporting module causes circular json reference

Tags: javascript, json, vuejs2

I am developing a simple javascript module for learning purposes. It looks like following:

```
function gen (props) {
    var test = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        test.push(props.start + i);
    }
    return test;
}

module.exports = function (props) {
    return gen(props)
}
```

I am calling this module as:

```
<script>        
    import gen from './gen.js'

    ...
    mounted: function () {
        var x = gen({start: 5});
        console.log(x);
    }
    ...
</script>
```

But I am getting `Converting circular structure to JSON` error. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Forgot to mention, this is in VueJS. The whole module is a separate file and I am importing it into one of components.

Comment: The code shown doesn't do anything with JSON.

Comment: I am not sure, I forgot to mention but it is in vuejs. Could the framework have something to do with this?

Comment: I think the error is coming from `console.log(x)`, can you confirm it by removing this, Also can you tell us what is you want to achieve, which can help the answer better, Also include more code from vue component, is source of error is not this.